# get gridview label field while clicking on linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to retrieve the value of label field by clicking on link button. it has to be fired only in onclick event only. i have tried with this , but it is giving null value.

```
protected void verifycount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      GridViewRow link = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;                
      Label qrcode = (Label)link.FindControl("lblqrcode");       
      string result=qrcode.text;
}
```

pls help do solve this

Comment: That should work. What is `null`?

Comment: it is returning empty value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your link button in grid view column as a command argument send the value the lable in that field.think you have

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="Attached Files" />
 <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:LinkButton ID = "lnkDelete" Text = "Delete" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("FileName") %>'
                                 runat = "server" OnClick = "DeleteHWAttachment" />
          </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then your code behind is like that,

```
protected void DeleteHWAttachment(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string filename = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void verifycount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      LinkButton Lnk = (LinkButton)sender;    
      string result=Lnk.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void verifycount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
        string qrcode = grdrow.Cells[0].Text;
    }
```

Make sure that all fields are bound fields except linkbutton